# Why does AVPlayerView not have a member named "player" in Swift

Tags: swift, avkit

I was trying to use `AVPlayerView` in Swift, but the compiler complaints that it cannot find a member named `player` in `AVPlayerView`.

[image: Error saying AVPlayerView does not have a member named "player"]

But `AVPlayerView` clearly does have a property called `player`.

[image: AVPlayerView class definition shows it has a property named "player"]

And other properties or methods are fine. It seems that only `player` is not recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You explicitly have to import the AVFoundation framework (which defines
the `AVPlayer` class):

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

let playerView = AVPlayerView()
let player = playerView.player
```

That might be considered as a bug in the (Swift view of the) AVKit framework.

Comment: Thanks! Going to fire a radar for this.